How to access a class method inside of function which is inside of another method or same method? In JavaScript
How can I access a class method inside of a function which is inside of a method?
Look the code if I am unable to illustrate what I mean!
//example.js
class Example {
  getA(value) {
    let x = 5;
    return value + x;
  }
  
  getB(value) {
    const func = function(value) {
      return this.getA(value)
    }
  }
}
let ex = new Example();
console.log(ex.getB(2))


I think there must be a way

A vanilla function has its own this. You need to .bind it, or use an arrow function.

getB returns nothing/undefined.

Yes it's returning undefined however in my actual code implementation it's returning this is undeundefined

The code makes no sense. getB defines a function, assigns it to func and discards it. Why would you expect console.log(ex.getB(2)) to print anything other than undefined?

@jabaa, yes I understood what I was trying to do. thanks for pointing out!
